# Use the return type of a method as an argument type of another method in a curiously recurring template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, crtp, expression-templates

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class E>
class vector_expression
{
public:
    auto size() const {
        return static_cast<E const&>(*this).size();
    }

    auto operator[](/* type equal to E::size_type */ i) const
    {
        if (i >= size())
            throw std::length_error("");
        return static_cast<E const&>(*this)[i];
    }
}; // class vector_expression

template<typename T, class Tuple = std::vector<T>>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<T, Tuple>>
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;

    size_type size() const {
        return m_elements.size();
    }

    value_type operator[](size_type i) const { /* ... */ }

private:
    Tuple m_elements;
}; // class vector
```

The type of the argument `i` of `vector_expression<E>` should equal `E::size_type`. For a plausible reason, `typename E::size_type` doesn't work here. For the same reason, `std::result_of_t<decltype(&size)(vector_expression)>` doesn't work here.

So, how can we do it, if we can do it?

Comment: Your example has an endless recursion in operator[] calls.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes, I know. I've simplified the code in order to focus on the relevant part. However, I've edited the code in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it explicitly as a template parameter to `vector_expression`:

```
template<class E, class size_type>
class vector_expression ...

template<typename T, class Tuple = std::vector<T>>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<T, Tuple>, 
                               typename Tuple::size_type> ...
```

**Edit:**

It is also possible to turn the problematic function into a member function template, so that it is not instantiated until the full class definition is seen:

```
template <typename K = E>
auto operator[](typename K::size_type i) const
{
    if (i >= size())
        throw std::length_error("");
    return static_cast<K const&>(*this)[i];
}
```

Comment: While this is technically working, I've hoped there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I like your second approach. It's not that as intuitive as the first one, but more maintainable from my point of view (cause we might have other situations in `vector_expression` with the same problem, but a different type (which we would need to add to the template parameter list, too, if we follow the first approach).